# FragmentDialog loose reference to activity

Tags: android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am using the support library to create dialogs using fragments.

And i Have the following code to show and dismiss the dialogs:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Create", "Create");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
    init();
    addListeners();
    addhandlerListener();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private void showDialog(final Class<?> classs) {
    if (classs.equals(AddressValidateProgress.class)) {
        addressValidateProgress = AddressValidateProgress.newInstance();
        addressValidateProgress.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
        Log.d("counter", "+1");
    }
    if (classs.equals(GPSSearchProgress.class)) {
        showDialog(gpsSearchloadId);
    }
}

private void dismissDialog(final Class<?> classs) {
    if (classs.equals(AddressValidateProgress.class)) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(addressValidateProgress).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        addressValidateProgress = null;
        Log.d("super", addressValidateProgressId + ":dismissed");
    }
    if (classs.equals(AddressChooseDialog.class)) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(addressChooseDialog).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        addressChooseDialog = null;
    }
    if (classs.equals(GPSSearchProgress.class)) {
        dismissDialog(gpsSearchloadId);
        Log.d("super", gpsSearchloadId + ":dismissed");
    }
}
```

If i start the application in portrait mode i can use the dialogs normally, i can even rotate the screen and the dialogs are reconstructed.
The problem is that if i start the application rotate the screen and click the button that open the dialogs i get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

It was caused by a static Handler declared